# read json data in java

Tags: java, json

I'm in a situation where I have to read the json data and insert it into Sqlite table. 
But the json data in this format :

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "data": {
        "userId": "873",
        "volume": "0.5",
        "schoolId": "0",
        "schoolName": "",
        "preferredLanguageId": "1",
        "fname": "robin",
        "lname": "singh",
        "email": "rob@live.com",
        "password": "password1111",
        "isParent": "0",
        "countryId": "254",
        "stateId": "143",
        "state": "",
        "city": "san diego",
        "coins": "0",
        "zip": "",
        "players": []
    }
}

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String uname=json.getString("fname");
```

But I'm not able to get the first name in the string uname.

Comment: Try `JSONArray list = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");` to get collection of all properties nested within the data property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String uname=json.getString("fname");
```

Is not working because the `fname` property is nested within the `data` property. Therefore you need to do something like the following:

```
String uname = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("fname");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String uname = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("fname");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the `data` property and then get the `fname` property. `fname` is inside the `data` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read "data" as a JSON object and then "fname" as a string.

There are many JSON viewers online, this is one of my favorite:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

```
String uname = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("fname");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get `data` object from your `JSON` string. Here is an example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
String uname = data.getString("fname");
```

Take a look at complete example [here](http://codedestine.com/how-read-write-json-in-java/).
Also [here](http://codedestine.com/json-editor.html) is a web based tool for creating/editing `JSON`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)